# Prevent process from starting using WMI?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I read up on detecting processes being started using WMI or via hooks.
However I need to be able to "block" the processes, as in prevent them from executing a single instruction.
Is there any solution to this?

The application is guaranteed to be ran with administrative privileges.

Answer (score -1):

It's been years since I did COM but short of editing the registry, I think the APIs you might want to investigate are either   CoGetInterceptor or CoTreatAsClass

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?